# Pricebook Maintenance pricing based on percent

Tags: pricebook

In our case we price Maintenance as a percent of opportunity.
How can we include in pricbook which is an SLA product which is a % of opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with "out of the box" functionality. There are several ERP-type applications on the AppExchange that may have this type of functionality. You could also simply write your own code to have this sort of feature.

Comment: I only have PE and I think I will need APEX and triggers to write my own code to handle it

Comment: Within PE, your only option would be a ISV solution.